# capistrano deploy error private pub gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

i tried to deploy my app to server after adding a gem called private_pub

it runs smoothly on local. but when i deployed using capistrano, failed to deploy appearing error code on the terminal.

```
 DEBUG [56a34683]   rake aborted!
 DEBUG [56a34683]   ArgumentError: The staging environment does not exist in /var/www/vendorpedia/releases/20170729083837/config/private_pub.yml
 DEBUG [56a34683]   /var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/private_pub-1.0.3/lib/private_pub.rb:22:in `load_config'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/private_pub-1.0.3/lib/private_pub/engine.rb:8:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
```

On last error message :

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as root@188.166.221.138: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
ArgumentError: The staging environment does not exist in /var/www/vendorpedia/releases/20170729083837/config/private_pub.yml
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/private_pub-1.0.3/lib/private_pub.rb:22:in `load_config'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/private_pub-1.0.3/lib/private_pub/engine.rb:8:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/vendorpedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/vendorpedia/releases/20170729083837/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

what should i do? realy need your help!

thanks!

Comment: Do you have a configuration for `staging` in your `config/private_pub.yml`?

Comment: @spickermann no mate.. its just default

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear: `ArgumentError: The staging environment does not exist in .../config/private_pub.yml`. You will need to add a `staging` configuration. See the gem's [README](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub#configuration)

Comment: @spickermann i change on production to my website production:
  server: "https://vendorpedia.co.id:4443/faye"
  secret_token: "09feb9a2aab72ae823bae95bcc10cfb7a626a0722f1b7d6cc83f64e21b3ba556"
  signature_expiration: 3600 # one hour but still error

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code 
ssh_options[:keys] = %w('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')

instead of
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)

Comment: can you tell me step by step mate?